Is it possible to integrate the search bar into the table header (of DataTables) instead of placing it outside?
When working with DataTables, I would like to move the search bar, which is currently positioned outside of the table, directly into the table header. For example, I have a column labeled "Name," and I want to place a text input field in the header of that column so users can filter by name. The question is whether this is possible with DataTables and how it can be implemented effectively. Here is some code:
@extends('v3.layouts.main')
@include('v3.cursus.components.bevestiging')
@section('content')
    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>
                    Cursus bestelverzoek:
                    <select
                            id="cursusSelect"
                            class="form-control d-inline-block ml-3"
                            style="width: 300px;">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecteer een cursus</option>
                        @foreach($cursussen as $cursusOption)
                            <option
                                    value="{{ $cursusOption->id }}"
                                    @if(isset($cursus) && $cursusOption->id == $cursus->id && !isset($_GET['herhaling'])) selected @endif
                            >
                                {{ $cursusOption->naam }}
                            </option>
                            @if($cursusOption->heeft_herhalingstraining == 1)
                                <option
                                        value="h_{{ $cursusOption->id }}"
                                        @if(isset($cursus) && $cursusOption->id == $cursus->id && ($_GET['herhaling'] ?? 0) == 1) selected @endif
                                >
                                    {{ $cursusOption->naam_herhaling }}
                                </option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentWrapper" style="display: none;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <i id="searchIcon" class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                <div id="loadSpinner" class="spinner-border text-primary d-none" role="status" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zoeken" placeholder="Zoek naar cursisten">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="fixed-table">
                        <table id="cursistenTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped dataTable"></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="fixed-table">
                        <table id="cursistenSelectedTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped dataTable"></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row justify-content-center mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <form method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <input id="hiddenCursusId" type="hidden" name="cursusId" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="klant_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->resellerKlant()->id }}">
                        <input id="hiddenCursisten" type="hidden" name="cursisten" value="">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn main-btn btn px-3 py-2">Verstuur bestelverzoek</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                let selectedCursisten = [];
                let selectedCursus = null;

                $('#cursusSelect').on('change', function() {
                    selectedCursus = $(this).val();
                    if (selectedCursus) {
                        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                        $('#contentWrapper').fadeIn(); // Laat de inhoud zien
                    }
                    cursistenTable.ajax.reload();
                    $('#hiddenCursusId').val(selectedCursus);
                });

                let cursistenTable = new DataTable('#cursistenTable', {
                    dom: 'rtp',
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    pageLength: 10,
                    ordering: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/sws_api/cursisten/<?php echo auth()->user()->resellerKlant()->id ?>",
                        data: function(d) {
                            d.excludedIds = selectedCursisten.map(item => item.id);
                            d.selectedCursus = selectedCursus;
                        },
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'id', visible: false },
                        { data: 'naam', title: 'Naam', render: DataTable.render.text() },
                    ],
                    responsive: true,
                    language: {
                        emptyTable: "Geen gegevens gevonden",
                        zeroRecords: "Geen overeenkomende resultaten gevonden",
                    }
                });

                let cursistenSelectedTable = new DataTable('#cursistenSelectedTable', {
                    dom: 'rtp',
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: false,
                    pageLength: 10,
                    ordering: true,
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'naam', title: 'Naam', render: DataTable.render.text() },
                    ],
                    responsive: true,
                    language: {
                        emptyTable: "Geen cursisten geselecteerd",
                        zeroRecords: "Geen overeenkomende resultaten gevonden",
                    }
                });

                $('#cursistenTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
                    let data = cursistenTable.row(this).data();
                    if (data) {
                        cursistenSelectedTable.row.add(data).draw(false);
                        cursistenTable.row(this).remove().draw(false);
                        selectedCursisten.push(data);
                        cursistenTable.draw(false);
                        $('#hiddenCursisten').val(JSON.stringify(selectedCursisten));
                    }
                });

                $('#cursistenSelectedTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
                    let data = cursistenSelectedTable.row(this).data();
                    if (data) {
                        cursistenTable.row.add(data).draw(false);
                        cursistenSelectedTable.row(this).remove().draw(false);
                        selectedCursisten = selectedCursisten.filter(item => item.id !== data.id);
                        cursistenTable.draw(false);
                        $('#hiddenCursisten').val(JSON.stringify(selectedCursisten));
                    }
                });

                $('#zoeken').on('input', function() {
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    cursistenTable.search(value).draw();
                });
            });
        </script>

@endsection
<style>
    .fixed-table {
        height: 445px;
        background-color: #f8f9fa;
        overflow-y: auto;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    }
    .fixed-table table {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    dee2e6
</style>


I am wondering if it is possible.

There is individual column filtering. Note that the filters here are at the bottom of the columns, which is probably because the header already has a function.

Yes, it's possible to rearrange the datatable's individual components however you see fit. Check out the 'dom' option.

Maybe this could help, https://live.datatables.net/saqozowe/70/edit. This example uses select, but it should be pretty simple to swap it out for a regular input
